# scp: ambiguous target when attempting to copy directory with an apostrophe and spaces in the name

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ssh, scp

I am trying to use scp to copy a directory by using ssh through windows terminal to connect to my mac and then use scp to copy a folder to my raspberry pi; I have tried many variations such as

```
scp -r "directory's name" myuser@myip:/directory/target
scp -r "'directory's name'" myuser@myip:/directory/target
scp -r "'directory'\''s name" myuser@myip:/directory/target
scp -r "directory\\'s name" myuser@myip:/directory/target
```

All to no avail, I realize I am having an issue with correctly using escape characters but cannot for the life of me work it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The missing colon between remote destination and directory target was a typo for the post on my part; however the format above doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The first version (`"directory's name"`) worked for me, although I'm not starting from Windows, and am running an old version of both macOS (Catalina 10.15.7) and Raspbian (buster). Are you running this command directly in the macOS shell, or is it part of a Windows command (i.e. will it be parsed by Windows before being passed to the macOS shell)?